# Cordova how to force app update when new update is reaching the AppStore?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, app-store, cordova-plugins

I know I can set the current version on the build and later check on the RESTapi if this is the updated version.
If it does not, I can display a message tells the user that in order to continue he has to update via Google Market / AppStore.

But I want this to be just automatically - I mean without leaving the app.

Something like:

A new must-have update is on, would you update now?
Yes / No.

When clicking Yes, it will download and update.
When clicking No it will say - this is a must have update, in order to continue you have to agree to update.

I have tried to search for some cordova plugin but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, updates are managed by the App Store/Play Store apps, you can't force anything in other apps from your own app.

Comment: But I can force the user to go the AppStore/Google Play and update, right?

Comment: yeah, you can check the version and if it's not latest you can send them to the App Store and Play Store. You can use InAppBrowser for that with _system param and using the store url of the app